# Autoconf version error during Octave installation with Homebrew

Tags: macos, octave, homebrew, autoconf

I am trying to install Octave using Homebrew on MacBook Pro 10.6.8. Here is the installation log:

```
asz /usr/share/autoconf/autoconf > brew install octave
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/octave/octave-3.6.4.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/octave-3.6.4.tar.bz2
==> Downloading patches
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file configure.ac
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1605 (offset 2 lines).
==> autoreconf -ivf
configure.ac:45: error: Autoconf version 2.62 or higher is required
configure.ac:45: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/gm4 failed with exit status: 63
aclocal: /usr/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 63
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 63
```

As you can see it complains about the version of autoconf being to low. However I did install the higher version of autoconf with brew

```
asz ~ > autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.69
(...)
```

I did update my PATH to point to this new version of autoconf,

Old autoconf was in:

```
asz ~ > which autoconf
/usr/bin/autoconf
```

New one is in:

```
asz ~ > which autoconf
/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin/autoconf
```

but Homebrew still does not see it (same error). While searching for solution I found this hint in response to similar problem quoting:

> This is coming from the run of aclocal, which is part of automake.
>   aclocal does not call the autoconf binary, so the *path* that your
>   autoconf is in doesn't matter. It *does* look at m4 macros, though, and
>   I'm guessing it's finding autoconf macros out of /usr/share, which would
>   correspond to the system autoconf which would be 2.61 on osx [Link to original post outside of Stackoverflow](https://lists.launchpad.net/drizzle-discuss/msg04936.html).

I don't understand what I should do with it.

- Can you tell me how do I update these macros to point to the new autoconf?
- Is there any other way to make autoconf work?
- What additional information can I provide you to help diagnose problem?

Answer (score 0):

just had your same problem. What I did was :

cd /usr/share
mv autconf autoconf.old
ln -s /usr/local/share/autoconf .

Now the problem is not the version anymore but some other variable :4/libtool.m4:827: _LT_LANG_DEFAULT_CONFIG is expanded from...
configure.ac:48: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_SILENT_RULES
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1

will see what comes out of the next search phase